# How to swipe a page using jQuery Mobile on Touchstart event in PhoneGap Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I have created a swipe app using `jQM`. it is working well.
But this swipe event performs after the sliding from left to right is completed. What i want is when user slides at the same time menu appear like sliding view is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

JQM 1.3.2 has three swipe events that can be modified in many ways.

From their docs: http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

> Triggered when a horizontal drag of 30px or more (and less than 75px vertically) occurs within 1 second duration **but these can be configured**:
>
> The swipe event can also be extend to add your own logic or
>   functionality. The following methods can be extended:

I would think you want to modify "**$.event.special.swipe.start**"

I am surprised that your event does not trigger quicker. Default settings state that all they need to do is move 30px in 1 sec. That is like the width of a pinky finger movement.

PS - while this may not be the "best answer." I really just did not want to type all this in the comments!

Good Luck! Hope this points you in the right direction.